# Kafka Limit Consumer Access and View of topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Problem Statement:
There is a kafka producer that produces to a certain topic. It emits a lot of information. I want to control a few things on consumer side.

1. I want to control who can listen to topic. (Kafka has ACL's I know about them)
2. I want to control what the consumer can see from the topic. i.e if consumer cares about certain fields he can only see those. If he wants more he needs to reach out to us.

   - I do not want to create topic per consumer since it too much to manage

Is there a way to implement this without it being a management nightmare. Any design Patterns blogs,3rd party software would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Kafka stores bytes. If you want to hide information, you'd have to override all deserializer functions in the client SDK

Comment: yes is there a good pattern of how that is being done. I am thinking it will have to be a jar which can create pojo based on some configuration that is managed somewhere.

Comment: You can use a `ConsumerInterceptor` interface, sure. But what about non-JVM clients?

Comment: Since I can control via ACL's who can consume. I know who clients are. Downside is I will have to interceptor for their language.Any better solutions you can think off.

Comment: I recall Apache Ranger being able to provide something like this? Maybe OpenPolicyAgent as well. But I've not personally implemented either, so maybe not. The other option is to have your producers implement asymmetric encryption at the field level to protect those fields and only consumers with a private key can read them, anyone else just sees raw, encrypted data